# Were any families allowed to stay on board any Starfleet ships during the Dominion War?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Larger ships like the Galaxy class carried many families before the war, but were there any families that remained aboard starships after it began? It seems unlikely because of the possibility for immediate deployment or a surprise attack.

Comment: Even if they did, would anyone actually allow their family to stay onboard? I know I sure wouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Unlikely.** The notion of having families on board ship is described by DS9 writer/produce Ronald D. Moore as an '*interesting idea, but one that didn't pan out*' and something that doesn't really bear up to scrutiny, especially once you're on a wartime footing.

> **Q. When Gene created TNG and the Enterprise-D, his ideal was to make
> Starfleet "family friendly," so servicemen and women wouldn't have to
> leave their families behind, and that all could be truly comfortable
> on a starship and call it a home.  In recent years, though, TPTB have
> done away with the "luxury liner" version of starships.... My
> question: was the concept and intent of the Galaxy-class ship flawed?
> Should all Starfleet ships be lean-and-mean military vessels?  Or is
> it still possible for a Starfleeter to have a family life and a
> shipboard career at the same time?**
>
> **RDM:** *I think that the "family friendly" starship notion was an interesting
> idea, but one that didn't pan out.  There was always something awkward
> about Picard ordering the ship into battle situations with kiddies
> running through the corridors.  And no matter how much lip service we
> paid to the "our families are part of our strength" concept, it never
> seemed very smart or very logical to bring the spouse and kids along
> when you're facing down the Borg, or guarding the Neutral Zone, or
> plunging the ship into uncharted spatial anomalies.*
>
> <sub><sup>[AOL Chat #50](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_Alpha:AOL_chats/Ronald_D._Moore/ron050.txt)</sup></sub>

That being said, there may have still been some on Galaxy-class ships, possibly those on longer-range missions and not being actively used for military service.

> **Q.** **Are there still families and children on board starships?**
>
> **RDM:** *Perhaps on some Galaxy-class ships, but I think this was an experiment that
> failed.*
>
> <sub><sup>[AOL Chat #9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_Alpha:AOL_chats/Ronald_D._Moore/ron009.txt)</sup></sub>